# Optimize select query along with where clause to use index scan in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table "offer_facts" with many columns including product_dimension_id ( foreign key for product dimension table) and source_name ( varchar ). Both of these columns are indexed . At the moment approximately there are 120K rows in this table. This table is constantly growing ( around 20K per day).

Below is the query and the output I get .

```
SELECT version() "PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit"

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT DISTINCT product_dimension_id from offer_facts WHERE source_name='customer_conti'
```

And the output is

```
HashAggregate  (cost=36619.24..36621.37 rows=213 width=4) (actual time=2654.272..2655.064 rows=399 loops=1)
  Group Key: product_dimension_id
  Buffers: shared hit=2697 read=17687
  ->  Seq Scan on offer_facts  (cost=0.00..35425.82 rows=477367 width=4) (actual time=0.021..1525.361 rows=479880 loops=1)
        Filter: ((source_name)::text = 'customer_conti'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 723466
        Buffers: shared hit=2697 read=17687
Planning time: 0.201 ms
Execution time: 2655.778 ms
```

I am not sure why it is doing Seq Scan and not Index Scan .

I have created index with

```
CREATE INDEX idx_offer_facts_dimensions ON offer_facts USING btree (source_name COLLATE pg_catalog."default", shop_dimension_id, time_dimension_id, date_dimension_id, source_dimension_id, product_dimension_id);
```

and I have vaccuumed and analyzed the table.

Comment: Why DISTINCT(product_dimension_id), with ( )'s? Is that some special DISTINCT function, instead of SELECT DISTINCT product_dimension_id?

Comment: @jarlh no there is nothing special about this. It is a normal distinct function . I think () doesn't matter ..

Comment: Unrelated but: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. Use `distinct product_dimension_id`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name removing the brackets didn't effect the query. I will edit the the question to remove the brackets anyways ..

Comment: I said it was unrelated. Putting columns in parentheses is not going to do what you think. It doesn't matter for a single column but `col1, col2` and `(col1, col2)`  are two different things in Postgres

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_dimension_id 
FROM offer_facts
WHERE source_name = 'customer_conti' ;
```

The optimal index is a composite index: `offer_facts(source_name, product_dimension_id)`.  Individual indexes on each column are not as useful.  This query *can* make use of an index scan; Postgres *should* be smart enough to find that execution path.

Comment: And I'd add that if this is a common use case for the system then it would not hurt to use a materialised view, or other summary logic, to avoid the need to run this query against a growing fact table.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I do have the composite index .. CREATE INDEX idx_offer_facts_dimensions
  ON offer_facts
  USING btree
  (source_name COLLATE pg_catalog."default", shop_dimension_id, time_dimension_id, date_dimension_id, source_dimension_id, product_dimension_id); ..

Comment: @SucceedStha ... The first two keys in the index need to be `source_name` and `product_dimension_id`, in that order.